# Add string variable into argument(python)

Tags: python, string, arguments

I want to add string variable to save the file name by argument

```
plt.savefig(args["plot." + str(fold_no)])
```

But I got keyError instead. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: This needs more details like, try to print args and then see if the key exist or not.
simply you can also use  args.get("plot." + str(fold_no), "some_default_value")

Comment: I'm sorry what is the example of "some_default_value"?